# Unable to install app in iOS 13.X devices which pushed via Test flight

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios13, testflight

Unable to install the app in iOS 13.X devices only when it is pushed via Test flight. Getting the below error.

```
iTunesMetadata.plist content supplied to install command specified bundleVersion (9) that did not match app's CFBundleVersion (0009)
```

Comment: Hi, what is the version of development target in project? And have you tried in other version of iOS device to check, such as iOS `14/12`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue.
My fix is: Remove leading 0s in Bundle Version (CFBundleVersion) in Info.plist.